# Create different runs of a program and use its output

Tags: python, output, python-3.4

Assume I have 2 modules: `caller_module.py` and `program_module.py`. I need through `caller_module.py` to create many runs of `program_module.py` (so that I get a different PYTHONHASHSEED on each run).

Then I need to use the output created in each run by `program_module.py` and do some comparisons on it.

**Question:**
How do I dynamically create different runs of `program_module.py` and how do I take its output? (comparing the output is easy to do)

Comment: Have you taken a look at the [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/subprocess.html) module?

Comment: @ig0774 I spent about 15 hours on trying to understand how to use `subprocess`  (along with other possible solutions), but I haven't figured it out yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not entirely clear to me what you are trying to do, what sort of arguments you need, etc. But as a first approximation, have a look at [`subprocess.check_output`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output). I'm guessing that you want something like this:

```
import subprocess
import sys

output = subprocess.check_output([sys.executable, 'program_module.py'])
```

This is essentially the bare minimum code to run a module called `program_module.py` in the current directory using the current Python executable. It should be roughly similar to executing `python program_module.py` from the command line or console.

You could wrap the `check_output` call in a loop to run as many times as you need.

Note that this assumes that [`sys.executable`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/sys.html#sys.executable) is a reasonable value in your configuration...

---

By default, `check_output()` will return anything that the invoked program writes to `stdout`. The easiest way to do this is via the built-in [`print()`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#print) function. The contents that you `print()` are returned by `check_output()` as a string, so the variable I have set as `output` in the above example is what you want to look at.

Comment: There is more context on what I am trying to do in my [edit history](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/32536661/1). I removed all those details because firstly i felt viewers don't really need it, and secondly viewers didn't bother reading a wall of text. Let me know if I should revert to that instead.

Comment: Your answer addresses successfully how to create different runs. Could you give some details on how to make `program_module.py` create an output? (Assuming that `program_module.py` creates a dict i need to use)

Comment: @user536231: See my edit, but from your edit history, you're already doing what you need to (i.e. `print()`ing)

Answer (score 0):

You may create process with [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) module. It has dedicated function named [check_output](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output) which allows you to grab stdout of the module. `env` keyword allows you to set hash seed for subprocess explicitly.

```
import sys
import subprocess

outputs = {}
for hash_seed in xrange(1024):
    outputs[hashseed] = subprocess.check_output([sys.executable, 'program_module.py'], 
                                                env={'PYTHONHASHSEED': str(hash_seed)})
```